# Panes disappear after dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro

I am trying to use Telerik's RadDocking control in an WPF application using Caliburn.Micro and MEFBootstrapper. Unfortunately, the panes disappear when I drag and drop them to the "right" place.

Repro steps:

- Drag one of the panes.
- Drop the pane on any of the arrows around the center wheel (see the screenshot at http://1drv.ms/1utkqSZ).

The application window is moved to background and the panes disappear.

If I drop the pane on any other place (left, right etc.), onto the wheel but not on the arrows around it or make it float, everything works as expected.

After the issue happens, the WPF Inspector shows just the OpenedScreens ContentControl in MainWindowView and the direct sibling ContentPresenter as the final node of the visual tree. However, all views still seem to be attached to all models (OpenScreensModel, FirstScreenModel and SecondScreenModels) and the OpenedScreensModel.Items collection still contains both the first and the second screen.

You can download the testing projects and see the screenshot at http://1drv.ms/1utkqSZ. The second project is the same as the first one but contains some debugging code.

Sample project structure:

- MEFBootstrapper: Settings to register Telerik conventions and make the Import[]/Export[] attributes do their magic.
- TelerikCaliburnMicroConvetions: Conventions to make the Telerik controls works in Caliburn.Micro by default. Part of it is from a public project on GitHub, the RadDocking convention is new made with collaboration with Telerik's support staff.
- CustomPanesFactory: Complimentary class for creating panes when created by Caliburn.Micro's convetion. It puts everything in the mainGroup pane group.
- FirstScreen, SecondScreen: Just same sample panes to show.
- MainWindowView: Just a holder of the OpenedScreens and opens FirstScreen and SecondScreen during initialization.
- OpenedScreens: Manages the screens. All opened screens models should appear as a pane on the main window.

How to fix it?